# Running an .exe from within a .bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I realize this might be a very basic question but I am slightly new to working with batch.

I am trying to use delprof to delete user profiles off multiple remote computers. I have Delprof.exe saved and can run it from a cmd window to put in different required arguments such as "/p /d:30". I can have my batch file run the application using the start command but it quickly closes the window.

I need to have delprof run from the batch but be interactive so it can prompt me with what profiles it has found and if I want to delete them. Basically Im trying to use this so I dont need to enter the arguments every time. I want it to be one click on the batch file and it will pop up with the profiles found and ask me which ones it should delete.

Comment: Sounds like a question for [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Comment: Doesn't the /p option on delprof already achieve what you want?

Comment: Perhaps open a command window and run the delprof from there to test if you have the complete syntax right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not clear on exactly what you want. But omitting start will probably do what you want. Which is run delprof as if you typed it at command line.

If not see the `set /p` command.

```
set /p remote=Enter Computer Name
delprof /c:\\%remote%
```

Comment: If you want the bat to stay open after running to read screen. Use pause. See `pause /?`.

Comment: This line, as last line in a batch file, only pauses if bat file double clicked. `If /i "%cmdcmdline:~0,6%"=="cmd /c" pause`

Comment: I found that just using: `delprof2 /p /ed:administrator` `pause`
worked. I didn't realize I could run it that way if they were in the same directory. Part of the problem was also that, if it doesn't find any profiles it closes the batch instantly, but I believe this is more an issue with the exe